# Error when trying to install tightvnc via ssh ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, ssh, vnc, remote

When I send the `apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver` commands the server says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.175.1) but it is not going to be installed
xfce4 : Depends: xfwm4 (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfconf (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfce4-settings (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfce4-panel (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfdesktop4 (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: thunar (>= 1.6.6) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: gtk2-engines-xfce (>= 3.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfce4-session (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfce4-appfinder (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: orage (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxfce4ui-utils (>= 4.12) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: desktop-base (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: thunar-volman (>= 0.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: tango-icon-theme (>= 0.8.90) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: xfce4-notifyd but it is not going to be installed
xfce4-goodies : Depends: xfce4-battery-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-clipman-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-cpufreq-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-cpugraph-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-datetime-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-diskperf-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-fsguard-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-genmon-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-mailwatch-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-mount-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-netload-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-notes-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-places-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-sensors-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-systemload-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-timer-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-verve-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-wavelan-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-weather-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-xkb-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: thunar-archive-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: thunar-media-tags-plugin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mousepad but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ristretto but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfburn but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-dict but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-screenshooter but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-taskmanager but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xfce4-terminal but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: xfce4-power-manager but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

what can I do?

Comment: So run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` If you still have a problem file a bug report against  `update-notifier` "update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.175.1) but it is not going to be installed" for unmet dependencies